# Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain...S). Centos7

Tags: centos7, bind, named-conf

I'm new to linux environment and trying to build a web hosting server for my few webistes. But my name servers are not pointing towards my server. I red many articles on many forums and used this command and it shows thsi error!

My Servers Public ip is: `103.159.66.155`
and name servers are as follow:

```
ns98.planetserver.cloud
ns49.planetserver.cloud




systemctl status named.service

● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/named.service.d
           └─cpanel.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-05-15 02:31:38 EDT; 23s ago
  Process: 20185 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 18326 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 15 02:31:37 103-159-66-155.cprapid.com bash[20185]: zone planetserver.cloud/IN: loading from mast...er
May 15 02:31:37 103-159-66-155.cprapid.com bash[20185]: zone planetserver.cloud/IN: not loaded due to...s.
May 15 02:31:37 103-159-66-155.cprapid.com bash[20185]: _default/planetserver.cloud/IN: not a valid number
May 15 02:31:37 103-159-66-155.cprapid.com bash[20185]: zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.... 0
May 15 02:31:37 103-159-66-155.cprapid.com bash[20185]: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
May 15 02:31:37 103-159-66-155.cprapid.com bash[20185]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
May 15 02:31:38 103-159-66-155.cprapid.com systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=e...s=1
May 15 02:31:38 103-159-66-155.cprapid.com systemd[1]: **Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain...S).**
May 15 02:31:38 103-159-66-155.cprapid.com systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
May 15 02:31:38 103-159-66-155.cprapid.com systemd[1]: named.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full
```

Config File: named.conf ---

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { any; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { any; };
    allow-transfer  { none; };
    recursion no;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
    channel default_debug {
        file "data/named.run";
        severity dynamic;
    };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
```

Comment: It looks like you may have malformed syntax in your named.conf.  Use the -l switch to review the "ellipsized" errors.